# Is it possible to use trigger hover as a toggle for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, triggers, hover

**QUESTION:** 
Is it possible to do something like this? I need to trigger hover events on click for mobile, and then toggle them off if you click on the same div/element.

```
$(function () {
     $('.grid-sarah').click(function () {
       $( '.grid-sarah' ).toggle(.trigger( "hover" ));
     });
});
```

**ANSWER:** 
After adding the requested

```
$(function () {
     $('.grid-sarah').click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     });
});
```

I added

```
    if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";
}
```

to my scripts and

```
.no-touch figure.effect-sarah:hover > figcaption h2, figure.effect-sarah.hovered > figcaption h2{}
```

to my css so that the toggle hover would still work, and the :hover would cease.

Thanks so much - [zachzurn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852546/zachzurn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your css to use a "hovered" class (In fact you can use any class you want):

```
.grid-sarah:hover, .grid-sarah.hovered{ /* Your CSS */ }
```

And modify your jquery to this:

```
$(function () {
     $('.grid-sarah').click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("hovered");
     });
});
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I'm using css that can't be treated that way. such as - figure.effect-sarah:hover > figcaption h2 {} and figure.effect-sarah:hover h2::after {} I don't think i could do it that way — right?

Comment: You definitely can do that. In hopes of keeping the answer more generic for others, here is the example of your specific css: figure.effect-sarah:hover > figcaption h2,  figure.effect-sarah.hovered > figcaption h2{}

figure.effect-sarah:hover h2::after, figure.effect-sarah.hovered h2::after{}

Comment: sweet thanks, I'm giving that a go now. How do I stop the hover state from being auto activated on click. I have no js telling it to trigger hover atm and it still triggers :hover on click on mobile.

Comment: You rule! I added 

if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";
}

To my scripts file, and .no-touch before my classes I didn't want activate :hover

 I.E .no-touch figure.effect-sarah:hover > figcaption h2, figure.effect-sarah.hovered > figcaption h2{} This way the hover toggle still works.